# Google Sheet REGEXMATCH

Tags: regex, google-sheets

can someone tell me what formula can represent the following statement :

- If in Cell **A1** there's value **A** or **B** or **C** or **D** then Value **X** must Show up in cell **B1**
- If in Cell **A1** there's value **E** **or** F or **G** or **H** then Value **Y** must Show up in cell **B1**

Thanks a ton!

I have tried REGEXMATCH function, but I wasn't able to mesh all the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=IFS(REGEXMATCH(A1,"A|B|C|D"),"X",REGEXMATCH(A1,"E|F|G|H"),"Y",1,)
```